# Finding camera position without calibration

Tags: opencv, camera, computer-vision, augmented-reality, homography

I have to find the camera position using several images from a football field. Using these images I can find the homography that transforms the points in the 3D model (in meters) into the points in the image (pixels). Each picture can have a different focal lengths, hence the camera intrinsics can change. I'm using OpenCV in C++.

I've found solutions for similar problems but either [you already have the camera calibrated, with a fixed focal length](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/2736/step-by-step-camera-pose-estimation-for-visual-tracking-and-planar-markers) (in this case you only need one image) or [you don't have the camera calibrated but you consider that its intrinsic doesn't change](http://www.epixea.com/research/multi-view-coding-thesisse9.html) (in this case you need at least 3 images).

Is there anyway to find the camera position in the 3D model without knowing anything besides the homographies (with different focal lengths)?

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: No.

If you don't have any additional information about the cameras, there is no way to uniquely position the cameras.  There would be multiple combinations of camera attributes & positions that would produce the same image.

You may be able to constrain the camera position along a certain 3D line, and reduce the problem to 1 degree of freedom, if that helps.